# How to change WASAPI record bitrate with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio, wasapi

I'm using NAudio to decode, play and record a MP3 Stream. For recording I use `WasapiLoopbackCapture` to save the stream to a wav file:

```
if (waveIn == null) {
  waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
  writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilename, waveIn.WaveFormat);
  waveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable);
  waveIn.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler(waveIn_RecordingStopped);
  waveIn.StartRecording();
}
```

I'm now searching for a solution to save the wav file not with 3072 kBit/s (what seems to be standard for the wasApi). The mp3 stream provides 128 kBit/s, so this would be a good bitrate for my wav file. I tried to modify the `waveIn.WaveFormat` but I didn't find the right properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately WASAPI does not allow you to change the sample rate for loopback recording. You have to perform your own sample rate conversion yourself afterwards. The `DmoResampler` or `WaveFormatConversionStream` classes in NAudio can be used for this.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Naudio's abstractions on wasapi but you can force windows to give you the audio in a specific bitrate/samplesize using the wasapi C++ API.
If that helps